# HTML parsing with lxml - how to keep empty content in resulting list?

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml, lxml.html

I am using lxml to parse an html file:

```
from lxml import html

tree = html.parse(myfile)
data = tree.xpath('//p/text()')
```

I have 300 `<p>text</p>` tags in my html file, but `len(data)` is only 250 because sometimes I'll have `<p></p>` in my html. I want these to be included in `data` either as a `'nan'` or `''`.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//p/text()` would only find you texts of `p` elements having a non-empty text.

Instead, find all `p` elements and call `.text_content()` for each one:

```
data = [p.text_content() for p in tree.xpath('//p')]
```

To demonstrate the difference:

```
>>> from lxml import html
>>> 
>>> 
>>> data = """
... <p>text1</p>
... <p></p>
... <p>text2</p>
... """
>>> 
>>> tree = html.fromstring(data)
>>> data = tree.xpath('//p/text()')
>>> len(data)
2
>>> 
>>> data = [p.text_content() for p in tree.xpath('//p')]
>>> len(data)
3
```